# var_dump(geoip_record_by_name) works but it doesn't print the result in webpage

Tags: php

Here is my issue.
When i do in cli the following command line it prints the result: `echo "<?php var_dump(geoip_record_by_name('8.8.8.8'));?>"|php7.2`

However when i create a php file geoip.php, put the following code in it and access to the this webpage **nothing is displayed**.

- I have correctly put in /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/geoip.ini this: extension=geoip.so
- I have installed the correct libraries: 
  pip install ipaddr
  apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
  apt-get -y install libgeoip-dev
  pecl install geoip-beta
- I have put the databases in /usr/share/geoip/GeoIPCity.dat and GeoIP.dat and GeoIPASNum.dat.

Can someone lend me a hand please?

Comment: check your error log

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i forgot to install php-geoip.
The problem is solved.